# How to set resizezable (when scrolling) background image to AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to create some view like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ifoZ.png)
 and 
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKNTa.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/test_background"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/information_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_comments">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this one information_content.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:text="Бар Чукотка \n Da Gudda Club"
        android:lines="2"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_place_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view_place_name"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/address_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/location_pointer"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Ул Ш.Калдаякова 69 "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="7.6"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="@drawable/button_rating"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not have any problems with recycler view and I just want to create app_bar_main.xml file for AppBarLayout view can anybody help to solve at least on of these problems?  If it is so much work just give idea to solve main problems

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by this way:

```
final float SCALE_MINIMUM=0.0018f;
   // Log.d(LOG_TAG,"scale density: "+scale+" image height in pixels"+mainBackdrop.getWidth());
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) appBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_backdrop);


            imageView.setScaleY(1 + (verticalOffset * SCALE_MINIMUM));

        }
    });
```